# Tab Error: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Tags: python

```
class SimpleBatch(object):
    def __init__(self, data_names, data, label_names, label):
        self.data =(data) 
          self.label= label
          self.data_names = data_names
          self.label_names = label_names

    @property
    def provide_data(self):
        return [(n,x.shape) for n,x in zip(self.data_names, self.data)]

    @property
    def provide_label(self):
        return [(n,x.shape) for n,x in zip(self.label_names, self.label)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The three lower lines in the **init** method are not the same at the first line in the method. Your tab spacing needs to be consistent throughout your code.

Answer (score 0):

You accidentally added tabs after "self.data =(data)"

```
class SimpleBatch(object):
    def __init__(self, data_names, data, label_names, label):
        self.data =(data) 
        self.label= label
        self.data_names = data_names
        self.label_names = label_names

    @property
    def provide_data(self):
        return [(n,x.shape) for n,x in zip(self.data_names, self.data)]

    @property
    def provide_label(self):
        return [(n,x.shape) for n,x in zip(self.label_names, self.label)]
```